# Elastic Beanstalk command line tool across regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the latest eb command line tool setup and had originally configured it with my two git branches using

```
eb init
```

Recently I had to deal with 2 different regions

```
us-west-1
   branchA
   branchB
us-west-2
   branchC
```

Before I would just do

```
git checkout branchA
eb deploy
```

Now I have to do

```
git checkout branchC
eb init --region=us-west-2
eb deploy
```

Is there any way to have the init state be automatic based on the branch name? I see the file .elasticbeanstalk.config.yml has configuration information, can I specify this information somewhere in there?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to specify it in .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml. I have not tried this with `default_region`, but it works great with `profile`.

It might look something like this now:

```
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: project-dev
  master:
    environment: project-prod
  staging:
    environment: project-staging
global:
  application_name: application_name
  default_ec2_keyname: key_name
  default_platform: Python 2.7
  default_region: ap-southeast-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
```

If you want a branch specific region you just move that value from the global section to the branch settings.

```
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: project-dev
    default_region: eu-west-1
  master:
    environment: project-prod
    default_region: ap-southeast-1
  staging:
    environment: project-staging
    default_region: ap-southeast-1
global:
  application_name: application_name
  default_ec2_keyname: key_name
  default_platform: Python 2.7
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
```